# вставить значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

подскажите почему при клике по пользователю он не вставляется в td, из функции не передает в глваную функцию

вот таблица

```
<tr data-index="5" data-new="0" data-id="9">
  <td style="" data-name="name">Сергей</td>
  <td style="" data-name="hdate">2025-10-20</td>
  <td style="" data-name="pdate">2027-10-20</td>
  <td style="" data-name="sale">25</td>
  <td style="" data-name="debit">2255</td>
  <td style="" data-name="credit">85</td>
  <td style="" data-name="balanse">25</td>
  <td style="" data-name="brakst">2525</td>
  <td style="" data-name="saldok">2118</td>
  <td style="" data-name="braksumma">52</td>
  <td style="" data-name="prihodsumma">0</td>
  <td style="" data-name="saldo">52</td>
  <td style="" data-name="prihodst">0</td>
  <td style="" data-name="ostatokst">25</td>
</tr>
```

список пользователей

```
<div class="modal-body" id="user-list">
                <li data-list-id="1">
    <div class="im-block">
        А
    </div>
    <div class="info-block">
        <span class="name">Администратор по умолчанию</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-list-id="6">
    <div class="im-block">
        С
    </div>
    <div class="info-block">
        <span class="name">Сергей</span>
    </div>
</li>
<li data-list-id="11">
    <div class="im-block">
        А
    </div>
    <div class="info-block">
        <span class="name">Антон</span>
    </div>
</li>
            </div>
```

скрипт

```
$(document).on("click", 'td[data-name="name"]', function() {
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {src: '#form-user'},
            type: 'inline'
        });

        $("#user-list li").click(function(){
            var pid = $(this).attr('data-list-id');
            name = $(this).find(".name").html();
            $.magnificPopup.close({
                items: {src: '#form-user'}
            });
        });
        $(this).html(name);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: не не то,вставляет предыдущее значение пользователя

Comment: Да, то. Ваша функция обратного вызова - это `$("#user-list li").click(function(){`.

Comment: можете подсказать кодом хотя бы на начальном этапе, ничего не понял из того что написано

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var namedCell = null;

$("#user-list li").click(function(){
  var name = $(this).find(".name").html();
  $.magnificPopup.close({
    items: {src: '#form-user'}
  });
  $(namedCell).html(name);
});

$(document).on("click", 'td[data-name="name"]', function() {
  namedCell = this;
  $.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {src: '#form-user'},
    type: 'inline'
  });
});
```